# Using javascript API to get video metadata based on video key

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

Our company has videos uploaded using JWPlayer's hosting services. Is there a way to pull a given video's metadata (title, description, etc.) by using their javascript API and passing in just the video key? Is there any way to do this without having to utilize any of their server-side API kits?

Answer (score 4):

While the player has functions to get metadata like getPlaylist() there are many instances where you are easier off using the JW Platform [feed URL schemes](http://apidocs.jwplayer.com/urls/feeds.html) to request video metadata instead.

There is also an undocumented but supported feed schema for JSON feeds http://content.jwplatform.com/feeds/KEY.json (where KEY is the media key of your video or playlist)